# ¿Cómo hacer desaparecer un componente con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

login.js

```
SplashScreenFn(){

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#splashOut").fadeOut(1500);
    },3000);
 
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".change-p").fadeIn(1500);
    },3000); 
} 


    render() {
            return (<div>
        
         <div id="splashOut"><SplashScreen className="splash" id="splash" /></div>  

        {this.state.logueado===false &&
        <Animated className="change-p" animationIn="slideInLeft" isVisible={true}>
            <Form className="bg-light w-90 mx-auto rounded shadow p-3 mt-4" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate >

                ....EL RESTO DEL CÓDIGO DE FORM
                
            </Form> 
        </Animated> 
        }
        </div>)
}
```

SplashScreen.js

```
class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div className="splash" >
            <img id="logoIndia" className="fadeIn" src={logoIndia}/> 
        {/*  <img id="logoSolo" src={logoSolo}/>*/}
        </div>)
    }
}
export default withRouter(SplashScreen);
```

Este es el código que tengo para hacer un *splash*, pero no puedo hacer desaparecer el componente *SplashScreen*, queda fijo y no me muestra el login.

En primer lugar, coloqué la función que tengo para hacer desaparecer el componente del *splah*, luego coloqué el código que tiene mi componente *splash*.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en el código?

Comment: Desconozco `reactjs`, pero ¿en qué momento se ejecuta la función `SplashScreenFn()`?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar delete() https://api.jquery.com/remove/

o si quieres ocultarlo hide() https://api.jquery.com/hide/

```
$("#id").delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer desaparecer un objeto en HTML5 con jQuery, es:

```
$().removeClass()
$().removeItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez necesitas desaparecer todo el componente padre "splash".
Puede ser con hide:

```
$(".splash").hide();
```

O con remove:

```
$(".splash").remove();
```